# Use Pro Shaders in Blender?

Tags: texturing

I own Element 3d and Pro shaders. More than anything, I'm curious to know if it would be possible to use pro shaders in blender to render in cycles. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: This seems more a question about formats. What format are the shaders in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time it's not possible to import the shaders directly into Cycles.

Currently Element3D can only export OBJ files, which doesn't help even if you applied a Pro Shader to a model in E3D because OBJ materials don't really map to Cycles material nodetrees. They doe import the UV coords as well as image textures if there is a .MTL material file included with the OBJ file.

If E3D could export to FBX format, you would be able to import a shader tree that was more Cycles compatible.

At this point, I think your only option would be to import the image texture(s) used in the Pro Shader you want (if you can find them in ProShader folder in your file system), and then try to recreate the shader in Cycles.